# How to connect to InfluxDB server(not local)

Tags: influxdb

I was given the name of the cluster node to connect to. I was told to target it as my influxDB server but I am not sure how to do that. Do I need to change some settings in the config file? if so, where and how? I do have information such as udername,pw, and database too.

Comment: What software or application are you trying to connect to your remote influxdb instance? If it is a nodeJS application then you can use the influxdb node driver but before we can go further, we need to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SamuelToh I figured out that you just run your Influx server like normal and you connect to the machine/node through the influx cli. E.g.  connect xxxxxxxx:8086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you just run your Influx server like normal and you connect to the machine/node through the influx cli. E.g. connect xxxxxxxx:8086